# Display CFGregorianDate without milliseconds

Tags: string, swift, time

I have a CFGregorianDate that displays in hours, minutes, seconds with milliseconds like so:

```
var elapsedTime:CFGregorianDate!
elapsedTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate((totalElapsedTime), nil)
var formattedDateString: String = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%05.2f", elapsedTime.hour, elapsedTime.minute, elapsedTime.second)
```

I just want to display hours, minutes and seconds (without milliseconds). I've tried changing the format: "%02d:%02d:%05.2f" to different combinations without success.

Comment: You could simply change the format to `"%02d:%02d:%02.0f"` to suppress the fractional seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
let dateString = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", elapsedTime.hour, elapsedTime.minute, Int(elapsedTime.second))
```

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work Leonardo - I thought it would.

Comment: I've just changed it Second property is a Double https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFGregorianDate

Comment: Perfect! I will accept your answer as soon as I can!